# After Zoom install: macOS forwards various requests to localhost

Tags: network, vpn, dns, malware, zoom.app

right on the day since I installed (and uninstalled) Zoom, various URLs began to be forwarded to `localhost`. Like:

```
$ traceroute -I googleadservices.com

traceroute to googleadservices.com (127.0.0.1), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.525 ms  0.061 ms  0.054 ms
```

Other sites and services are affected, too, so I had to grab the IPs behind the domains and hardcode things in the `/etc/hosts` to be able to work, it looks like this now:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section

#manual quickfixes:
140.82.113.3    github.com
140.82.118.4    gist.github.com
151.101.52.133  gist.githubusercontent.com
104.28.28.240   coronazaehler.de
172.217.2.106  firebasestorage.googleapis.com
104.26.1.95  myairbridge.com

157.240.18.19 cdn.fbsbx.com
# BEGIN section for OpenVPN Client SSL sites
127.94.0.1  client.openvpn.net
127.94.0.2  openvpn-client.vpn.leondrino.com
# END section for OpenVPN Client SSL sites
```

Using NordVPN doesn't change anything, but with TOR I can access everything.
What could be wrong ?

Comment: What are your DNS settings?  Is it pointing to localhost?  And are you running something like a local DNS service on your computer?

Comment: I don't belive this is due to DNS because `traceroute` is following the path to the *host*.  To confirm, try tracerouting using the IP - you'll see it still goes to the localhost.  It seems something wrote some static routes looping back to your localhost for some reason.  Boot to [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) and see if the problem persists.  This will confirm if something is running that's causing this behavior.

Comment: What would be a way to trace this down ? No malware detector finds anything, apparently the host this MITM attack (I heavily suppose it is one) is talking to is uninstalled already. Wireshark hints activity towards localhost upon calling affected domains, but I absolutely can't tell anything from what it is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievable, after months of digging around cluelessly, I seem to have found it out. Apparently, the IPs

```
103.86.99.99
103.86.96.96
```

are part of some malicious part, they appear here:

```
$ scutil --dns
resolver #1
  search domain[0] : 
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.178.1
  nameserver[1] : fd00::7eff:4dff:fe7e:56fa
  if_index : 5 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  nameserver[0] : 103.86.99.99
  nameserver[1] : 103.86.96.96
  if_index : 14 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000003 (Reachable,Transient Connection)
```

and this resolver #2 isn't shown in any DNS settings in the system config.

running `$sudo scutil`, I found these IPs in this entry:

```
>get State:/Network/Service/39118383-7AC1-4270-AA42-7F97B4505F57/DNS

>d.show


<dictionary> {

  ConfirmedServiceID : 39118383-7AC1-4270-AA42-7F97B4505F57

  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 103.86.99.99
    1 : 103.86.96.96
  }
```

The top answer here showed me how to replace this entry with a proper one. After that, I ran:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf

sudo ln -s /var/run/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

What kind of crap could that have been ?